# Solution with sub-projects in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a classlibrary that consists of 5 different smaller projects. I have a solution file that contains them all in order to build them easy and in the right order.

How do I go about adding theese projects to TFS in the simplest way. I'd like for each one of the subprojects to have their own branches e t c, but where do I put the solution files e t c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the easiest way is to branch the complete solution, this avoids messing with changing relative folders in the solution, or having to set up and maintain non-trivial workspace mappings.